# Naming conventions for methods that throw exceptions (C++)?

Tags: c++, exception, naming-conventions

We are working on a medium to large C++ codebase, and are in the process of refactoring it to get it in better shape.

Recently it was suggested that we expand our naming convention for functions that (may) throw exceptions, to make it easier to determine - at a glance - if a function may `throw` exceptions (directly or indirectly by calling functions that `throw`).

While I find the ability to more easily get that information would be neat I cannot shake the feeling that this might lead to trouble as there is no tool-assisted way to verify and enforce that convention - thus you cannot really rely on the convention (beyond it giving hints).

As I feel torn and uncertain about this I decided to seek advice from here:
So, is using such naming conventions a good idea/worth the effort and are there established conventions for that?

Comment: Why not simply use the [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) specifier? As in `noexcept(false)` for functions that can throw.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea... Seems like Hungarian notation for exceptions. If you know a function cannot throw, tag it as `noexcept`. But be aware of the fact that it says that the function cannot fail.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that this question does not belong here. There are good programming reasons why you shouldn't introduce the necessity to change function names willy-nilly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that might be a way, depending on what exactly my teammembers intend (should you be able to tell from directly looking at the name?) - though the comments here have reinforced my gut feeling that the idea (while good in intention) brings little to none real "gain".

Comment: @gnat Yeah - "once bitten, twice shy" for me on following other user's suggestions to move questions to other sites...

Comment: Exceptions can be thrown from surprising locations.  The set of functions that can be demonstrated to not throw will be quite small.  Not worth distinguishing functions that can throw from those that cannot.  Java forced annotating functions with their exceptions... probably seemed like a good idea at the time, but turns into a maintenance quagmire pretty quickly (and still has an escape hatch for non-annotated exceptions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really will not determine anything. It would be yet another idiosyncratic convention that's unenforceable at the programming stage: what happens if someone refactors a function and forgets to change its name?

If someone is compelled to change a function name due to changes in the exceptions that can emanate from that function then you could introduce breaking changes into your program due to overload resolution: messing about with function names can have unintended side-effects.

From C++11 you can use the `noexcept` specifier which might be helpful.

Comment: actually i'd be more worried about a refactor that makes a function that is named to not throw such that it can throw. Almost nothing is worse than false security

Comment: @user463035818 My thoughts exactly - and since this would be a **new** naming convention this would apply (initially) for 99% of the codebase... At the very best it would be a hint as to be "careful, this function may throw" instead of "this function does not throw". Oh well....

Comment: @CharonX note that `noexcept` also does not save you from carefully considering if a function may throw or not, as a `noexcept` function that does throw will terminate your program. I dont think there is a easy solution

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it is a good idea to have a naming convention, but applying in practice is a real pain. My experience with two huge code base taught that you only start to apply such conventions (if conventions did not exist earlier) only with new designs.

The thumb rule we followed (for all functions, including the ones that do not throw) is to reflect the component name (it part of) and functionality (that it serves) in the method names and then an informative text in the exception message.

The exceptions thrown contains a message that tries to reflect the business/usage context if the software directly interacts with a human end user, or a more technical message if its internal to the logs. There is no golden bullet for naming conventions and is mostly domain driven.

It entirely depends on how mature the software department is in the company and what domain it is.

Answer (score 0):

It can be adopted from C#.
For example for dictionary you have Add and TryAdd.

In my example I am providing a dll and export a function that MUST be named Start.
Also since it is dll export it SHOULD not throw.

But now I want to include this function in tests. Here I actually want it to throw, so I can see stack on test reports.

Now despite all the arguments, the function name shall be informative. Here I use StartUnsafe.